# How can I get a file address in a directory above in C#?

Tags: c#, file, filepath

I want to get an address from a file from the current directory, for example:
I'm positioned in `MiProyecto/Socket/bin/Debug`and I want to go to `MiProyecto\Ranking\Ranking.xml`from an application that runs on `Socket/bin/Debug`.

I have looked for a way to do it in a generic way but I have not found a concrete solution. I do not want to use *OpenFileDialog*.

The only thing I know is that to get the current directory of the application that is running is with `string path = Application.StartupPath;` but I don't know how to climb from that path to `Ranking\Ranking.xml`

I tried too:

`string fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\");`
`Console.WriteLine("\n\n"+fullPath);`

Output on screen:

[image]

Comment: Using `Path.Combine()` and `..\ ` to go up one directory?

Comment: Will this file *always* be in the same relative path from the executable?  If your application has a dependency on a file system folder which *could* change from one executing environment to the next then you might consider having a config value for the folder.

Comment: Try create a new System.IO.DirectoryInfo instance using your startup path. That object should have a .Parent property or similar for you to nav upwards.

Comment: @ne1410s Can you show me an example please?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't work, Another solution?

Comment: Why it didn't work? Any errors? Please post your code, so we can reproduce it.

Comment: @Rich I have already added it

Comment: It is unlikely you are going to deploy your project on the user's machine.  Certainly not in bin\Debug.  And if you do anyway then it is likely to fail.  You do need to start thinking about where you are going to store those files.  Just don't make it hard to find them back.

Comment: *I'm positioned in MiProyecto/Socket/bin/Debugand I want to go to MiProyecto\Ranking\Ranking.xmlfrom an application that runs on Socket/bin/Debug* -- Quick question on this statement. I've already given an answer, but my question to you is, why is the output from what you've shown in the image different than what you've stated here? I don't see a `MiProyecto/Socket` path in your output at all.

Comment: @Chris I did it as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic way to get **MiProyecto** folder's path, then merge it with **/Ranking/Ranking.xml**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string startupPath = Application.StartupPath;
            Console.WriteLine(startupPath); // .../MiProyecto/Socket/bin/Debug

            string folderName = "MiProyecto";
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(startupPath);

            // Loop until found MiProyecto folder
            while (true)
            {
                if (di.Parent.FullName.EndsWith(folderName))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    di = new DirectoryInfo(di.Parent.FullName);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(di.Parent.FullName); // .../MiProyecto
        }
    }
}
```

By this way, you'll always get **MiProyecto** folder's path

```
MiProyecto/A/B/C/D/E/Debug 
MiProyecto/Ranking/Ranking.xml
```

Comment: Thanks. Something like that was looking

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything with `fullPath` after writing it to the console. You need to append fullPath to your SerializadorRanking call -- i.e. SerializadorRanking(fullPath + "Ranking.xml");

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\"); 
Console.WriteLine("\n\n"+fullPath);
serializadorRanking = new SerializadorRanking(fullPath + @"Ranking\Ranking.xml");
```

Conversely, you can just append the entire string through the `Path.Combine` function.

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\Ranking\Ranking.xml");
serializadorRanking = new SerializadorRanking(fullPath);
```